# Check if the value of a key in one array is equal to the value of different key in another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, matching

I have 2 multidimensional arrays and I want to get the 1st array where the value of  `[file]` key in array 1 is equal to value of `[folder_name]` key in array 2

```
$arr1 = [
    [
        'is_dir'      => '1',
        'file'        => 'hello member',
        'file_lcase'  => 'hello member',
        'date'        => '1550733362',
        'size'        => '0',
        'permissions' => '',
        'extension'   => 'dir',
    ],
    [
        'is_dir'      => '1',
        'file'        => 'in in test',
        'file_lcase'  => 'in in test',
        'date'        => '1550730845',
        'size'        => '0',
        'permissions' => '',
        'extension'   => 'dir',
    ]
];

$arr2 = [
    [
        'dic_id'      => '64',
        'folder_name' => 'hello member',
        'share_with'  => '11',
    ],
    [
        'dic_id'      => '65',
        'folder_name' => 'hello inside',
        'share_with'  => '11',
    ],
    [
        'dic_id'      => '66',
        'folder_name' => 'in in test',
        'share_with'  => '11',
    ],
];
```

I have tried while looping 2 arrays and getting to one array but it is not success.

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: @sampath giving your expected answer to help paint a better picture

Comment: @hazelcodes I expected same array as array1.

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe Please check my answer below

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe *"I expected same array as array1"* doesn't make much sense, because if so, you could just use array1. Please elaborate.

Comment: Confirm that you want to keep all arrays in array1 that have a 'file' that can be found as 'folder_name' in array 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can iterate both arrays inside each other to check until we have a match.

Please be aware that this shows only the first match. If you want to keep all matches you should use another helper `array` to store first array values that matches to second array.

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($array2 as $id => $item) {
        if($value['file'] == $item['folder_name']){
            // we have a match so we print out the first array element
            print_r($array1[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid a double loop that gives a time complexity of *O(n²)*, you could first create the set of "folder_name" values (as keys), and then use that to filter the first array. Both these operations have a time complexity of *O(n)* which is certainly more efficient for larger arrays:

```
$result = [];
$set = array_flip(array_column($arr2, "folder_name"));
foreach ($arr1 as $elem) {
    if (isset($set[$elem["file"]])) $result[] = $elem;
}
```

`$result` will have the elements of `$arr1` that meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();
$arr3 = array();
$arr1[] = array('is_dir'=>'1','file'=>'hello member','file_lcase'=>'hello member','date'=>'1550733362','size'=>'0','permissions'=>'','extension'=>'dir');
$arr1[] = array('is_dir'=>'1','file'=>'in in test','file_lcase'=>'in in test','date'=>'1550730845','size'=>'0','permissions'=>'','extension'=>'dir');
$arr2[] = array('dic_id'=>'64','folder_name'=>'hello member','share_with'=>'11');
$arr2[] = array('dic_id'=>'65','folder_name'=>'hello member','share_with'=>'11');
$arr2[] = array('dic_id'=>'66','folder_name'=>'in in test','share_with'=>'11');

foreach($arr1 as $a){
    foreach($arr2 as $a2){
        if($a['file'] == $a2['folder_name']){
            $arr3[]=$a;
        }
    }
}
$arr3 = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $arr3))); // remove duplicates
var_dump($arr3);
```

$arr3 contains the resultant array.